# Create array with numbers +10/-10, where middle one is 0, depending on what length I want

Tags: javascript, arrays, math, numbers

I need to dynamically create array, knowing only how long I want it to be. So for example I need array to be 3 long so I need array = [-10, 0, 10], if I need array 9 long it will be [-40, -30, -20, -10, 0, 10, 20, 30, 40] etc. How can I do it automatically?

Comment: what did you attempt, seem pretty easy math and a loop.

Comment: Start with `new Array(length)` where `length` is the length of the array. There's also a fill method to look into https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/fill

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another solution with `Array.from`:

```js
const createArray = (length) => Array.from({length}, (el, i) => Math.round(i - length / 2) * 10);

console.log(createArray(1))
console.log(createArray(3))
console.log(createArray(9))
```

Answer (score 3):

You can simply get the result using `Array` with `fill`

Since you only want `0` at the center that input should be `odd`.

```js
const end = 9;
let start = Math.floor(end / 2);

const result = [
  ...Array(start).fill(0).map((_, i) => start * -10 + i * 10),
  0,
  ...Array(start).fill(0).map((_, i) => (i + 1) * 10)
]

console.log(result)
```